# Как сделать функцию возвращающую данные через while

Tags: php

Есть функция которая работает с массивами:

```
function make(){
    $arr1 = ['1'],
    $arr2 = [5, 6, 7];
    $arr3 = [5, 2, 9, 0, 6];

    // return <by turns>
}
```

по идее, эта функция должна возвращать эти массивы.. я понимаю, что можно вернуть все сразу и потом парсить.. но хотелось бы через `while`... то есть при каждой итерации в `while`, должен по-очереди получать `arr1`, `arr2`, `arr3`

Comment: Вообще вернуть несколько переменных из функции - невозможно. Если только не склеить их в один массив. По хорошему было бы создать несколько функций и в каждой формировать и возвращать свой массив, но видимо в вашей логике это невозможно и массивы должны формироваться совместно. Итог - формируйте массив в которому будут храниться все возвращаемые массивы и возвращайте их.

Comment: меня интересует через `while`, как/, допустим, работает `fetch_assoc` из `mysqli`

Comment: @thyie криво сформирован ваш вопрос.

Comment: Метки "алгоритмы" и "циклы" здесь не нужны, вопрос исключительно по синтаксису php.

Comment: скажите куда копать? по каким словам?